# How to construct a unique hash for a tuple in PHP

Tags: php, hash, hashcode

Does a unique hash function exist for a tuple given the following constraint in PHP

```
tuple length is 3

(int_1, int_2, enum)

1. int_1 has a length of 10
2. int_2 has a length of 10
3. enum has cardinality of 3 (3 total possibilities)
```

Does php hash function, like md5, or sha256 guarantee an unique hash for every subset of the tuple?

For example

```
(2, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(3, 1, 2)
```

all have different resulting hash

Comment: Hash functions have collision rate, therefore you're after a perfect hash function because you have a finite (although large) set, and as far as I'm aware - there's no perfect hash function included with PHP out of the box. You can try googling for perfect minimal hash function and using one of available extensions. However, sha256 is *most likely* sufficient for your needs. Until someone with more experience in this area pops in to explain, I'd simply say (based on a hunch, no facts at this point) that sha256 should be fine. Side note - integers are always 10 in length or up to 10 in length?

Comment: What do you need the hash function for? Since a hexadecimal representation of MD5 is 32 characters long, wouldn't it take up more storage space than simply concatenating the numbers together?